# SSMA mySQL to SQLServer. Migrate only part of the table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-migration

I need to migrate a series of tables from `mySQL 5.6 -> SQLServer 2016`. A couple of these tables are extremely large (`6.10^9 rows, billions of records`).

I've tried to migrate them using SSMA but, unfortunately, the process takes over a week and frequently crashes before it is completed.

My questions are:

> 1) Is there a **better alternative**, e.g. free software tools? *Any* suggestions welcome.
>
> 2) If not: is it possible to configure SSMA to migrate **only parts** of the table (e.g. 10%)? An option is to migrate the table to a .SQL file, then run it in SQLServer as a query. The problem then is opening a file that can easily be 50-100 GB.
>
> 3) Are there any **SSMA tweaks** that can speed up the migration? E.g. the options file has parameters such as the buffer size & executing from Server side/client side  -but no documentation explains the advantages.

Comment: Maybe https://dba.stackexchange.com/ participants can help?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. Not v. familiar with all the SO webs. Shall I copy the question there or does it get flagged automatically?